# How to avoid echo and noise in javascript for webrtc

Tags: audio, video, chat, webrtc

I am trying to implement a webrtc-based chat room. And I encountered the following problems in laptop. Without connecting to any other peer, just use getUserMedia(), I can get local video stream.

When I unmuted the `<video>`, echo happened.

Then I wear headphones, and found there is a continued noise. And I can hear my voice clearly.

I tried to turn down the volume, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If @tom-vLine 's answer has solved your issue, please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Make sure that you are muting the **local** `<video>` element if you have it in the DOM:

```
<video id="vid1" autoplay="true" muted="muted"></video>
```

See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/8MGqZ0OzS8I/LMd-tzGAX1sJ) on the discuss-webrtc mailing list for more details and the [WebRTC samples](http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/js/demos/html/pc1.html).

Comment: If you mute it, it won't capture any sound, will it?

Comment: The stream will still capture sound even if the local playback element is muted. Muting the element in the DOM will just mute local playback. To mute the outgoing audio stream itself, you'll want to do localMediaStream.getAudioStreams()[0].enabled = false or localMediaStream.getVideoStreams()[0].enabled = false to keep the sound going but disable the video stream. This assumes you saved the media stream somewhere in your onaddstream() callback.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the echo without losing the sound?

Comment: @DNM, you won't loose sound with this mute.

Comment: Thank You.. This answer saved me.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. This fixed it, and @BenjaminNolan explaining that if it's muted you don't lose the audio from the recording was also helpful. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 6):

Do the followings:

1) In localVideo do the this:

localVideo.volume = 0;

localVideo.muted = 0;

2) Do same for the remoteVideo also:

remoteVideo.volume = 0;

remoteVideo.muted = 0;

Comment: `muted` attribute didn't help, maybe because of Angular 4 which I use. But this works perfectly `document.getElementById('yourVideo').volume = 0`

Answer (score -9):

To resolve noise related issue, you should set autoplay=false for localstream.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: autoplay=false just not allow the video to be played automatically. It doesn't have anything to do with audio.