# Stopping own audio in stream

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to implement video chat in my application with webrtc.

I am attaching the stream via this:

```
 getUserMedia(
                {
                    // Permissions to request
                    video: true,
                    audio: true
                },
                function (stream) {
```

I am passing that stream to remote client via webrtc.

I am able to see both the videos on my screen (mine as well as of client).

The issue I am getting is that I am getting my own voice too in the stream which I don't want. I want the audio of other party only.

Can you let me know what can be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406193/how-to-avoid-echo-and-noise-in-javascript-for-webrtc.

Comment: Yes, mute the video element: `<video id="selfie" autoplay muted></video>`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the "muted" attribute to your local video tag as follow  :

```
<video muted="true" ... >
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting **`echoCancellation`** flag to **`true`** on your constraints.

[4.3.5 MediaTrackSupportedConstraints](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#widl-MediaTrackConstraintSet-echoCancellation)

W3.org
Media Capture and Streams

> When one or more audio streams is being played in the processes of
>   various microphones, it is often desirable to attempt to remove the
>   sound being played from the input signals recorded by the microphones.
>   This is referred to as echo cancellation. There are cases where it is
>   not needed and it is desirable to turn it off so that no audio
>   artifacts are introduced. This allows applications to control this
>   behavior.

Comment: As the quote suggests, `echoCancellation` defaults to being on, so this is likely not the OP's issue.